# Getting unindentified index error, read threads about it here but still don't understand

Tags: php

I'm trying to output all movie titles from a data file. And keep getting unindentified index errors, now despite reading explanations I still don't understand it maybe because english isn't my first language.

My json file:

```
    "movies": [
        "Jurassic Park",
        "James Bond",
        "once upon a time in the west",
        "Waterworld"
    ],
    "recipes": [
        "Lasagne",
        "Pizza",
        "Salad"
    ]
}
```

My php file:

```
/**
 * Get the data from a JSON file.
 *
 * @return string
 */
function getData($filename)
{
    $json = file_get_contents($filename);

    return json_decode($json);
}

echo '<ul>';


foreach(getData('04-data.json') as $movie) {
    echo '<li>';
    echo ($movie['04-data.json']);
    echo '<li>';
}

echo '</ol>';
```

Error: Notice: Undefined index: 04-data.json in C:\xampp\htdocs\04-fix-me.php on line 20

Comment: Which line is line 20?

Comment: "echo ($movie['04-data.json']);"

Comment: Look, the simplest way here is to add in a var_dump($movie) or print_r($movie) so you can see what is going on here. Oh and Comment out your line 20 when you do this so you get an ouptut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After closely looking your code, I come to know that you have to do below modifications in  your `foreach()`

```
foreach($array->movies as $movie) { // do $array->movies
    echo '<li>';
    echo $movie; // use $movie
    echo '<li>';
}
```

***Note:-***

1.`json_decode()` without second parameter as `true` will give an stdClass Object array.

2.Since you need to access movies, so apply foreach on `$array->movies` array

Sample example to understand:- https://3v4l.org/6aTIY

If you will apply `true` in `json_decode()` then `foreach()` syntax will become

```
foreach($array['movies'] as $movie) {
  //rest things are same
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I know how to explain this properly, but the problem is this line right here:

```
    echo ($movie['04-data.json']);
```

`$movie` is already decoded. `04-data.json` is the name of the file you are opening. Unless you expect your decoded json to have something under the file name--which is unlikely--then this is wrong. It should be a a key of the decoded json.

If you don't know what key you actually need, use `var_dump($movie)`. That will show you what key you actually need in `$movie`